# Issue selecting dropdown option with selenium webdriver(python)

Tags: python, selenium, select, drop-down-menu, webdriver

Trying to make a small script that helps me fill in table

I can't seem to be able to select from a dropdown list using selenium. after running the code multiple times it seems to randomly not work on some rows but it never breaks down at the same spot twice.

For some reason, it works fine on the first 2 dropdown boxes but the last 2 won't seem to work consistently(deductible and company).

heres what I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from random import randint

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.ehail.ca/quotes/?1494142398325")

for x in range(5):

driver.find_element_by_name("button").click()


acres = 100
croptype = "Wheat"
qrt = "NW"
sec = randint(1,16)
twn = randint(1,30)
rng = randint(1,30)
mer = "W3"
ded = "Full"
comp = randint(1,7)
cov = 100


for w in range(1,8):

     w = str(w)


     element = driver.find_element_by_name("acres"+w)
     element.send_keys(acres)

     select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('cropComboboxId'+w))
     select.select_by_visible_text(croptype)

     select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("quarterComboboxId"+w))
     select.select_by_visible_text(qrt)

     element = driver.find_element_by_name("section"+w)
     element.send_keys(sec)

     element = driver.find_element_by_name("township"+w)
     element.send_keys(twn)

     element = driver.find_element_by_name("range"+w)
     element.send_keys(rng)

     select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("meridian"+w))
     select.select_by_visible_text(mer)

#THIS IS WHERE THE TROUBLE STARTS!

     select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("deductible"+w))
     select.select_by_index(5)

     select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('company'+w))

     for index in range(len(select.options)):
     select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('company'+w))
     select.select_by_index(1)

element = driver.find_element_by_name("coverageperacre"+w)
element.send_keys(cov)


element = driver.find_element_by_name("quoteForm").submit()
```

I have tried selecting by index, name, id, text, pretty much everything but I cant even find a consistent breakdown point. in fact the odd time it will run without an error. the error I get is usually though is "cant locate element with index/name/id 'whatever'"

any help would be greatly appreciated.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two dropowns options are populated only after data is filled in previous fields. You can wait until the options exists before choosing from them

```
options_size = 0
while options_size == 0:
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("meridian" + w))
    options_size = len(select.options)

select.select_by_visible_text(mer)
```

The `select` element is refreshed when populated, so it should be relocated to prevent `StaleElementReferenceException`